# JHipster - Some CSS files did not appear in vendor file made by Gulp

Tags: gulp, jhipster, production, gulp-useref

I have this in main CSS:

[image]

And My vendor is this:

[image]

**Why when I run Production mode material-icons.css and md-data-table.css did not appear?**

Gulpfile.js

```
// Generated on 2016-04-23 using generator-jhipster 3.0.0
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant-fork'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    flatten = require('gulp-flatten'),
    del = require('del'),
    wiredep = require('wiredep').stream,
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handleErrors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');


var config = require('./gulp/config');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return es.merge( 
        gulp.src(config.bower + 'bootstrap/fonts/*.*')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist)),
        gulp.src(config.app + 'content/**/*.{woff,woff2,svg,ttf,eot,otf}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist)),
        gulp.src([config.app + 'robots.txt', config.app + 'favicon.ico', config.app + '.htaccess'], { dot: true })
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
    );
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});



gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('inject', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js').pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
});

gulp.task('wiredep', ['wiredep:test', 'wiredep:app']);

gulp.task('wiredep:app', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /angular-i18n/,  // localizations are loaded dynamically
                'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/' // exclude bootstrap js files as we use ui-bootstrap
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));

    return stream;
});

gulp.task('wiredep:test', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.test + 'karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /angular-i18n/,  // localizations are loaded dynamically
                /angular-scenario/,
                'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/' // exclude Bootstrap js files as we use ui-bootstrap
            ],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\/\.\.\//, // remove ../../ from paths of injected JavaScript files
            devDependencies: true,
            fileTypes: {
                js: {
                    block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
                    detect: {
                        js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                    },
                    replace: {
                        js: '\'src/{{filePath}}\','
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.test));
});

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'registroApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'registroApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap:
            '(function () {\n' +
            '    "use strict";\n' +
            '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
            '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
            '})();\n',
        constants: {
            ENV: 'dev',
            VERSION: util.parseVersion()
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'registroApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap:
            '(function () {\n' +
            '    "use strict";\n' +
            '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
            '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
            '})();\n',
        constants: {
            ENV: 'prod',
            VERSION: util.parseVersion()
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('test', ['wiredep:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'pom.xml'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/css/**/*.css', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['wiredep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'inject');
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    runSequence('install', serve);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'wiredep:app', 'ngconstant:prod'], 'inject', 'assets:prod', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Build.js (For gulp task)

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    lazypipe = require('lazypipe'),
    footer = require('gulp-footer'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
    prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    useref = require("gulp-useref"),
    revReplace = require("gulp-rev-replace")
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
    handleErrors = require('./handleErrors');

var config = require('./config');

var initTask = lazypipe()
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(footer, ';');
var jsTask = lazypipe()
    .pipe(ngAnnotate)
    .pipe(uglify);
var cssTask = lazypipe()
    .pipe(prefix)
    .pipe(cssnano);

module.exports = function() {
    var templates = fs.readFileSync(config.tmp + '/templates.js');
    var manifest = gulp.src(config.revManifest);

    return gulp.src([config.app + '**/*.html',
        '!' + config.app + 'app/**/*.html',
        '!' + config.app + 'swagger-ui/**/*',
        '!' + config.bower + '**/*.html'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        //init sourcemaps and prepend semicolon
        .pipe(useref({}, initTask))
        //append html templates
        .pipe(gulpIf('**/app.js', footer(templates)))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', jsTask()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssTask()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.html', htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true})))
        .pipe(gulpIf('**/*.!(html)', rev()))
        .pipe(revReplace({manifest}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
}
```

Bower.json

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "registro",
  "appPath": "src/main/webapp/",
  "testPath": "src/test/javascript/spec",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.2",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.2",
    "angular-translate": "2.11.0",
    "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat": "2.11.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.11.0",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.11.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.18",
    "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.2",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.30",
    "angular-i18n": "1.5.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.2.5",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.2.3",
    "angular-material": "1.0.7",
    "material-design-icons": "^2.2.3",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.10",
    "jquery": "2.2.2",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "modernizr": "3.3.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "12.0.4",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.2.2",
    "swagger-ui": "2.1.4",
    "angular-material-data-table": "^0.10.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.2",
    "angular-scenario": "1.5.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "2.2.2"
      }
    },
    "material-design-icons": {
      "main": [
        "iconfont/material-icons.css"
      ]
    },
    "messageformat": {
      "main": [
        "messageformat.js",
        "locale/es.js",
        "locale/en.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.2",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.2",
    "angular-material": "1.0.7",
    "jquery": "2.2.2"
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. I used **JHipster (generator-jhipster 3.0.0)**.
2. In Dev mode **everything works good**.
3. These *.css dependents are **added automatically** **by Gulp**.

Comment: When in dev mode, how did material-icons.css and md-data-table.css appear in your index.html? Did you insert them manually or was it done automatically by gulp?

Comment: Can you post your gulpfile? thx

Comment: I added more details! Thanks!

Comment: Which version of JHipster?

Comment: // Generated on 2016-04-23 using generator-jhipster 3.0.0.

Comment: Can anybody resolved thid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that some files do not have an initial comment, so cssnano did not separate it in lines.